# Trying to make my word2vec code more efficient

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have a word2vec program that works on smaller corpora of novels, but not on bigger ones (i.e. it has worked on corpus of 1k but not 2k.) The problem occurs in the pre-processing. Any idea on how to improve it? Is TreebankTokenizer outdated or something? Are there libraries I need to update? Thanks.

Edited: What I mean by "doesn't work" is that the kernel dies in Jupyter Notebook. I don't get a Python error message.

```
#importing libraries
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os
import gensim
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#naming directory
base_dir = "/Users/XX/Desktop/test_corpus"
all_docs = []
docs = os.listdir(base_dir)

#tokenizing process
tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
files = glob.glob(f"{base_dir}/.txt")
titles = [Path(file).stem for file in files]

#make text lower-case and tokenize
def make_sentences(list_text):
    all_txt = []
    counter = 0
    for txt in list_text:
        lower_txt = txt.lower()
        sentences = sent_tokenize(lower_txt)
        sentences = [tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
        all_txt += sentences
        #print(len(sentences))
        #print("\n")
        counter += 1
    return all_txt
sentences = make_sentences(all_docs) #this is the line the kernel dies on

#training model
test_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
sentences,
min_count=2,
vector_size=200,
workers=5)

test_model.wv.most_similar("river", topn=5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error message you're getting? (If you get a Python error traceback, editing the entire traceback into your question will help potential answerers understand exactly which steps are failing.) How do you know, or why do you suspect, that the problem is in the preprocessing?

Comment: Good question. So, I'm doing this in Hathi Trust via a remote desktop connection. Generally, either the kernel dies or I get a server timeout.

Comment: Can you add logging/printing/flushing, at the level of steps in your process or even individual files, to pinpoint the exact step/file where the otherwise-generic hang/exit happens? As one example of the kind of thing such pinpointing will help distinguish: maybe there's one worst-case document, or maybe the size of your larger corpus (in any order) is exhausting memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions:

Process files one by one: Instead of loading all the files into memory at once, process them one by one or in smaller batches. This approach reduces the memory load during tokenization.

Use a generator: Instead of storing all the tokenized sentences in memory, consider using a generator to yield sentences one by one. This way, you don't need to store the entire corpus in memory, which can help with memory usage.

Use a more memory-efficient tokenizer: You can experiment with the WhitespaceTokenizer from NLTK or the tokenize function from the gensim.utils module. See if that helps.

Try pre-processing on disk: Instead of loading the entire corpus into memory, you can modify your code to read and process files directly from disk.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I process files one by one, how does word2vec access it all? Doesn't it need to all go into one doc? Also, can you tell me more about what you mean by using a generator? What libraries/etc. would that involve?

Answer (score 0):

As it is likely there is a memory-exhaustion aspect to your problem, you should ultimately, as @sebastian-demian suggests, be streaming the data via an 'iterable' Python sequence into the `Word2Vec` model. Then, only one document will be consuming main memory at a time - rather than loading the full dataset in its raw form, then also creating a duplicate in its preprocessed form.

Even then, there's a chance it's "one worst-case document" that's always causing the problem.

Are your 2nd 1000 docs potentially far larger than your 1st? How does he size-on-disk of the full 2k docs compare to the RAM of your machine?

If you add logging to show incremental progress (by filename & count of raw words processes), and try alternate orderings of the documents, does the failure always occur at a specific doc, or near a specific total-size? (For such logging, it can be useful to print/flush the *next* doc's name/stats before processing, rather than siply report it when completed. Also, perhaps your logging can show some measures of the total memory usage of the Python process at each step, to see if it blows up just before failure.)

With regex-based tokenization, occasionally extremely odd (or pathologically-crafted) input can cause worst-case compute/memory behavior. (That'd be less likely in long-established libraries, but not impossible.)

Finally, two other notes about your approach that aren't related to the failure, but could affect the quality of your results:

- `min_count=2` (or indeed anything lower than the default `min_count=5`) is almost always a bad idea with an algorithm like `Word2Vec`. It needs many varied examples of each word's usage to have a chance of learning a good vector for each word. It's usually better to *drop* words with too few examples – pretend they're not even there, virtually squishing their more-common neighboring-words closer together – than have that bloat the model size, & slow the training, & introduce noise into the patterns learned from better-represented words.
- due to internal implementation limits, any individual text (one tokenized list of words) to `Word2Vec` only supplies its *first 10,000 words* to the optimized training code. **Words beyond the 10,000th token are ignored.** As you mentioned your corpus is novels, this may be an issue if you are supplying each novel as a single giant text. (Splitting longer texts into chunks that are fewer than 10k words is the usual workaround. When using an adequately-size corpus, the extra synthetic 'breaks' – lost word-to-word contexts – have a negligible impact on quality.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Do you have an idea for how to split the novels into 10,000 token chunks? My coding knowledge is somewhat basic unfortunately.

Comment: It's possible that your approach - breaking things into sentences first, which are unlikely to be over 10k tokens – has already avoided the problem. If running `print(max(len(s) for s in sentences))`, once your global `sentences` already set up, shows any value under 10000, you're already OK. If you do have an issue, a fix inside your `make_sentences()` would just be a couple lines, but if you need help with that after trying to solve, best to ask as its own question.